# Using tf.metrics.auc for training and validation

Tags: tensorflow

Is there a proper way to use `tf.metrics.auc` when using the same model for both training and validation?  I currently have my model implemented as a class and am using the `tf.data` string handle to swap between the training and validation data.  Because the `tf.metrics.auc` function creates local variables, are there additional steps that I need to take to ensure that they are not being shared between the training and validation?

Ultimately I'd like to feed the area-under ROC and PR values to a `tf.summary.scalar` where I can see training and validation side-by-side, so this further complicates things as using a `tf.variable_scope` splits the plots into separate sections in Tensorboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve this by creating a `reset_op` that I used to zero-out the local variables before preforming the summary step

```
eval_reset_ops = []
for scope in ['outcome_' + str(i) for i in range(cfg.num_class)]:
    for var in tf.local_variables(scope=scope):
        eval_reset_ops.append(tf.assign(var, tf.zeros_like(var)))
```

I'm then running the following section to produce the summaries.

```
_ = sess.run(eval_reset_ops)
for _ in range(n_summary_batches):
    eval_metrics, tr_losses = sess.run([model.eval_ops, model.losses])
summary = sess.run(merged)
train_writer.add_summary(summary, step)
train_writer.flush()
```

In this case, `model.eval_ops` is a list of the update ops produced by `tf.metrics.auc`.

As in...

```
auc, auc_op = tf.metrics.auc(
    labels=labels, predictions=prob, num_thresholds=1000,
   updates_collections='eval_updates', curve='ROC')
aupr, pr_op = tf.metrics.auc(
    labels=labels, predictions=prob, num_thresholds=1000,
    updates_collections='eval_updates', curve='PR')
eval_ops = [auc_op, pr_op]
```

This seems to work fine.  I hope someone finds this useful or can point out how to improve it.